# vectorizing "for" loop with bidirectionally related variables

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Last week I asked the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658199/vectorizing-gibbs-sampler-in-matlab
Perhaps it was not that clear what I want to do, so this might be more clear.
I would like to vectorize a "for" loop in matlab, where some variables inside of the loop are bidirectionally related. So, here is an example:

```
A=2;
B=3;

for i=1:10000

  A=3*B;
  B=exp(A*(-1/2))

end
```

Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot vectorize this loop, because you always update your variables.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Excel calculation indicates that this quickly converges to 0.483908 (after much less than 10000 loops - so one way of speeding it up would be to check for convergence). If *A* and *B* are always 2 and 3 respectively, you could just replace the loop with this value.

Alternatively, using some series analysis you might be able to come up with an analytical expression for *B* when *i* is large - although with the nested exponents deriving this is a bit beyond my own abilities!

**Edit**

A bit of googling reveals [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights). Wikipedia states that for a tetration of *x* to infinity (i.e. *x^x^x^x^x...*), the solution *y* satisfies *y = x^y*. In your case, for example, 0.483908 = e^(-3/2)^0.483908, so 0.483908 is a solution. Not sure how you would exploit this though.

Wikipedia also gives a convergence condition, which might be of use to you: x lies between e^-e and e^1/e.

**Final Edit (?)**

Turns out you need Lambert's W function to solve for equations of the form of *y = x^y*. There seems to be no native function for this, but there seems to be something in the FileExchange - see [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/09/02/the-lambert-w-function/) and [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43419-the-lambert-w-function).